# Software App to make a transparent outline box?

Tags: windows, screen-recording, desktop-client, portable, color

I need a program to do this:

Basically, its just a program.exe file that does the following:

1. Has a Exterior border
2. Translucent inside

Its sort-of-similar to [Desktop Coral](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/split-your-desktop-into-two-using-desktopcoral-windows/) in terms of function. Other similar programs would be stardocks

But in the sense that the box will look like this

[image: frame]

I need this so I can make borders around make screencast/ .gif before I make them

EDIT: I intend to run an autohotkey script so that this window is always on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified an existing autohotkey script [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script

```
b:=10   ; border in px . This is black border
t=false ; variables are set by default to false, this line not needed but added for clarity

;----------------
; This Initializes the window
;----------------

Gui,+Resize                 ; window resizable (drag)
Gui, Color, EEAA99          ; Initializes Color so not-everything transparent
Gui +LastFound              ; Makes GUI the same background color as your regular window GUI apps
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99  ; Sets transparency
Gui,Show,w500 h500          ;  This sets width and height
return                      ; sends input

;------------
; Below is HotKey
;------------

F1::           

    t:=!t                                                           ; T is false default, changes to true upon first F1 push 
    if t {                                                          ; makes the "black border" unmovable window

        Gui, -Caption +ToolWindow +LastFound -Resize  +AlwaysOnTop   ; "ToolWindow: Provides a narrower title bar but the window will have no taskbar button" -Caption "removes border and title bar",       
        Gui, Color, Black                                           ; This sets color of border, causes temporary "black screen flash"
        WinGetPos,,,w,h
        q:=w-b, z:=h-b                                                                         ; precalculates border
        WinSet, Region, 0-0 %w%-0 %w%-%h% 0-%h% 0-0  %b%-%b% %q%-%b% %q%-%z% %b%-%z% %b%-%b%   ; Creates "black border"
    }
    else {                                                          ; This secion resets to default 

        Gui, +Caption -ToolWindow +LastFound +Resize -AlwaysOnTop              

        Gui, Color, EEAA99 ;               
        Gui +LastFound  ; Make the GUI window the last found window for use by the line below.
        WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99  ;

        WinSet,Region
    }
return
```

With it, I can press <kbd>F1</kbd> to lock in a border that can't be moved unless F1 is pressed again (it also sits as the top most windows too). Press <kbd>F1</kbd> again and you can move the border freely. I made the positional window transparent so you can see what you'll be looking at ahead of time.

I added many annotations on my script. I did not make the original though here on [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/52e9f0/software_app_to_make_a_transparent_outline_box/)

[image: Animation]

You can use this AutoHotKey function to make quick screencast gifs, pre-annotated borders on screenshots too